# Input function get wrong value after recall in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem is when i input value for array 2d with value valid, everything done but when i input wrong value for totalRow or totalColumn variable then my Input function forced me to input double and get value in 2nd.
It is my code:

```
public static void input() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.println("Input total totalRow: ");
        totalRow = sc.nextInt();
        // verify value input must be a positive integer and greater than zero
        if (totalRow <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Input value must be a positive integer and greater than zero!");
            input();
        }

        System.out.println("Input total totalColumn: ");
        totalColumn = sc.nextInt();
        // verify value input must be a positive integer and greater than zero
        if (totalRow <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Input value must be a positive integer and greater than zero!");
            input();
        }

        // check case array must be square array
        if (totalRow != totalColumn) {
            System.out.println("Array must be square!");
            input();
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        // print message when user input other than integer
        System.out.println("Please input an integer!");
        input();
    }

    // initialize array with totalRow and totalColumn
    array = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];

    // input value for array
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn; j++) {
            array[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Example: I enter 2 and a for totalRow and totalColumn: message appear and i re-enter is 2 and 2, but i have entered 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 for array and value get from 5.

Comment: You might want to not use recursion to repeat for inputs

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of things here that are making your code to fail:

1. Typo: you are checking `totalRow <= 0` twice (copy paste error for sure)
2. If condition not met, then you call input again:
   doing this will make a recursive implementation of the method, that can lead to a not desired repetition of the sequence, driving crazy the user and the developer
3. you are forgetting that scanner.nextInt does not consume the last newline character of your input

I would suggest to modify the Code by doing something like:

```
if (totalRow <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Input value must be a positive integer and greater than zero!");
        //input();
        }

        System.out.println("Input total totalColumn: ");
        totalColumn = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        // verify value input must be a positive integer and greater than
        // zero
        if (totalColumn <= 0) {
        System.out.println("......
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Recursion algorithm. Even it works for a correct input, foe a wrong input it will repeatedly ask for values. Since when you make any mistake **Input()** function will start again from the beginning. So if you want to use recursion better to use separate functions for **input_Total_Column()** and **input_Total_Row()** .
And there is also a copy paste error. You are checking **totalColumn<=0** twice in your code.
//Your code//

`for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {

```
    for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn; j++) {

        array[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);

    }
}
```

}`

if you enter the values in a raw this seems to be a incorrect logic. charAt(0) will return a charactor at the inedex 0(Only . So always it wold be returning the charactor at begining.  Try it like this.
string array_input= sc.nextLine();
split the string using .split() function.
then you can easily convert the values to integer using Integer.parseInt() at corresponding string value.